# Event delegation from target to all inner elements when HTML is dynamically appended?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-delegation

I have this basic HTML that represents a button, I want to attach a click event, but this button is appended dynamically to the container through a an ajax function, so because this is not present initially in the DOM, I'm attaching the event to the container in this way

```js
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  
  var t = e.target.classList;
  if( t.contains('button-outer') ) console.log(e.target);
  
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-outer {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-inner{
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="button-outer">
    <div class="button-inner">BUTTON</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works, but obviously only when I'm clicking on on the padding part of the outer div. To fix this I have to change the if statement in a way that it will contains the inner part too, like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  var t = e.target.classList;
  if( t.contains('button-outer') || t.contains('button-inner')) console.log(e.target);
  
});
```

I think that this is a little inconvenient, because sometimes the inner part could have other classes, or could be an icon, a link, it is a little difficult to create specific statements each time, so question is:

How can I propagate the event starting from outer to all inner elements when the button is dynamically appended?

Comment: `if (e.target.closest('.button-outer'))` should do it

Comment: @ChrisG really good! but why this is not working if I put the same condition in a switch statement like this `switch(true){ case t.closest('.button-outer'): console.log(e.target); break; }` it doesn't fires, but with the if statement it's ok

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't fire"? There's just a break; there, the switch statement (which is horrible coding style btw) doesn't really do anything?

Comment: @ChrisG I forgot to put the console.log,  anyway it doesn't do anything. Obviously I will never use the switch statement in this way, it's just to provide a basic example. Sometimes I have click events attached to something bigger like an ajax table, and I'm using the switch statement to provide different actions for each part of the table(like row helpers etc)so I don't think that is an horrible way.

Comment: @ChrisG this can be fixed by adding !! before like this `switch(true){ case !!e.target.closest('.button-outer'): console.log(e.target); break; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach your event handler when the button is created, in your ajax function.

But if you need to do it the way you are doing it, you can use [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), it will traverse all of the target's parents until it finds your query.

```js
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  
  var t = e.target;
  if(t.closest('.button-outer')) console.log(e.target);
  
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-outer {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-inner{
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="button-outer">
    <div class="button-inner">BUTTON</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: really good! but why this is not working if I put the same condition in a switch statement like this `switch(true){ case t.closest('.button-outer'): break; }` it doesn't fires, but with the if statement it's ok

Comment: Because for that switch to work, the case has to be true, t.closest('.button-outer') returns an Element, but the if statement parses the result to a boolean, [as specified here.](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.2)

Comment: I feel so stupid, I never thinked about this difference, anyway I fixed this adding !! before like this `switch(true){ case !!t.closest('.button-outer'): console.log(t); break; }` now is perfect for the real project. thank you

Comment: glad I could help. But I suggest what I said before in my response, attaching the event listener to the button when its created is a far better solution than this one.